# Enabling APR for Tomcat 6 on Ubuntu Maverick 10.10

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat6

I have installed tomcat6, libapr1 & libtcnative-1 on Ubuntu Maverick.

However, when Tomcat starts it says it is using "org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol" instead of loading APR.

Is there a simple way to get this to work? Any other missing packages to be installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works if you enable this line in `/etc/tomcat6/server.xml`:

```
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="off" />
```

In earlier versions, this was not required.